# What is the difference between @State and @ObservedObject, can they both be used to persist state?

Tags: swiftui, observedobject

When I Googled "State vs ObservedObject" the first [result](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject) was from Hacking with Swift and it said about `@ObservedObject`:

> This is very similar to @State except now we’re using an external reference type rather than a simple local property like a string or an integer.

Can I use `@ObservedObject` to create persisted state? Is it as simple as **`@State` is for simple properties and `@ObservedObject` is for complex objects**, or is there more nuance to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### `@ObservedObject` does not persist state

> Can I use `@ObservedObject` to create persisted state?

On its own, you cannot. The Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state_and_data_flow) has this to say about `@State`:

> A persistent value of a given type, through which a view reads and monitors the value.

But I found no mention of persistence with `@ObservedObject` so I constructed this little demo which confirms that `@ObservedObject` does not persist state:

```
class Bar: ObservableObject {
  @Published var value: Int

  init(bar: Int) {
    self.value = bar
  }
}

struct ChildView: View {
  let value: Int
  @ObservedObject var bar: Bar = Bar(bar: 0)

  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
      Text("param value: \(value)")
      Text("@ObservedObject bar: \(bar.value)")
      Button("(child) bar.value++") {
        self.bar.value += 1
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var value = 0

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Spacer()
      Button("(parent) value++") {
        self.value += 1
      }
      ChildView(value: value)
      Spacer()
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever you click on the `value++` button, it results in a re-render of `ChildView` because the `value` property changed. **When a view is re-rendered as a result of a property change, it's `@ObservedObject`s are reset**

[image: screenshot]

In contrast, if you add a `@State` variable to the `ChildView` you'll notice that it's value is not reset when the `@ObservedObject` is reset.

### Using persisted state with `@ObservedObject`

To persist state with `@ObservedObject`, instantiate the concrete `ObservableObject` with `@State` in the parent view. So to fix the previous example, would go like this:

```
struct ChildView: View {
  let value: Int
  @ObservedObject var bar: Bar  // <-- passed in by parent view

  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
      Text("param value: \(value)")
      Text("@ObservedObject bar: \(bar.value)")
      Button("(child) bar.value++") {
        self.bar.value += 1
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var value = 0
  @State var bar = Bar(bar: 0)  // <-- The ObservableObject

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Spacer()
      Button("(parent) value++") {
        self.value += 1
      }
      ChildView(value: value, bar: bar).id(1)
      Spacer()
    }
  }
}
```

The definition of the class `Bar` is unchanged from the first code example. And now we see that the value is not reset even when the `value` property changes:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: The same behavior as in your second example can be achieved, if you replace '@State var bar = Bar(bar: 0)' by '@ObservedObject var bar = Bar(bar: 0)' in contentView.

Comment: @user3687284 that's true only if `contentView`'s properties never change.

Comment: I have been doing this but I cannot figure out when `Bar` would get `deinit`ed here? It seems like possibly never?